# How to delete a record when only @RID is known

Tags: orientdb

I'd like to retrieve the class name of a given @RID so I can delete the record. I don't know its class name or wether it's a vertex, an edge or something else. How to do it via SQL or the Java API(both would be equally fine)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via **SQL** you can use

```
select @class from @Rid
```

[image]

**Java**

```
OrientGraph g=new OrientGraph(yourPath); 
String _class= g.getElement(new ORecordId(9,0)).getProperty("@class");
```

Delete record:

**Sql**

```
delete from 9:0 unsafe
```

you can see http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/SQL-Delete.html

**Java**

```
g.getRawGraph().getRecord(new ORecordId(9,0)).delete();
```

Comment: Your solution works fine, thanks. Anyway, there seem to be some cases, at least in the 2.2 beta, where both querying and deleting don't work this way. I've got some records that are byte arrays and stored in the cluster `default`. They can't be queried or deleted using SQL (from the console). Nevertheless, deleting the records via Java API works in those cases.